# Delete/unlock the [job-definition] questions locked by merges

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Pretty much everything in this tag needs deletion, but there are two old "merges" that make some of the questions impossible for the community to delete, namely:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9944/what-is-the-difference-between-software-engineer-and-software-developer

> merged by Yannis♦ Nov 6 '12 at 15:26
>   This question was merged with What are the key differences between software engineers and programmers? [closed] because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165625/what-is-the-difference-between-web-designers-and-developers

> merged by maple_shaft♦ Oct 29 '12 at 18:33
>   This question was merged with What are the boundaries between the responsibilities of a web designer and a web developer? [closed] because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

I assume there's no need to reiterate why job definition questions are off-topic and delete-worthy, so could a moderator please nuke these for the rest of us?

Comment: does it make sense to historically lock ["key differences"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/4951/31260)? 6 years old, 77K views, 3 top answers look respectable. Lower score answers look bad but not too awful - just "bad enough" to let readers see why this kind of questions is not welcome anymore

Comment: Honestly, I'd rather just nuke it and everything like it from orbit so we can move on with our lives and get back to **answering good, on-topic questions** instead of playing speculative and fruitless mindgames with the faceless masses and sometimes equally faceless powers that be. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: you mean, powers that be who can't even bother to do such a little thing as setting [distinct background for historically locked posts](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7828/31260), so that they make less of a broken window for inexperienced site visitors? Okay, consider me convinced

Answer (score 1):

I deleted both of these merge sources for you.  Hopefully this allows you to cast delete votes on the merge targets if you so wish. I am not touching those for right now but if you are still blocked from casting a delete vote then let me know.